# Confidence interval for variance

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Let's say we have **X**, a random vector that follows $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. My book asks me to find a confidence interval for $σ^2$ , the variance, if $μ$ is known.

It begins by taking that $$S^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(X_{i}-μ)^2}{n}$$

Next step, it considers the following function $$Y=\frac{n*S^2}{σ^2}$$
which follows $\chi_n^2$ .

Next step, we need to find $c_{1},c_{2}$ so that $P=[c_{1}<Y<c_{2}]=γ$
where $γ=1-α$ is our confidence level.

At other examples, where our distribution was symmetrical, it defined $c_{1},c_{2}$ as $-z_{α/2},z_{α/2}$ respectively, where $α/2$ is the probability of our distribution to be above $c_{2}$ or below $c_{1}$.

However, in this example our distribution isn't $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, but instead $\chi_n^2$, which is not symmetrical. For our convenience, it says, we will still consider it symmetrical and consider $c_{1},c_{2}$ as $x_{n,1-α/2}$ and $x_{n,α/2}$ respectively.

And this is what I can't understand. Can you please explain me why at the first $x$ the index has $1-a/2$ but in the second it has $α/2$, even thought it said it considers it symmetrical?
I don't know if I'm making any sense guys because different teachers might teach the same stuff in different ways. If you can, please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a random sample of $n$ observations $X_i$ from $\mathsf{N}(\mu, \sigma^2),$
with $\mu$ known and $\sigma^2$ unknown, then $\frac{nV}{\sigma^2} \sim
\mathsf{Chisq}(df = n),$ where $V = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i = \mu)^2.$
[I prefer to reserve the notation $S^2$ for the case where $\mu$ is
unknown and estimated by $\bar X.$]

Then, to make a $1 - \alpha = .95$ confidence interval (CI) for $\sigma^2,$ we can find values $L$ and $U$ that cut 2.5% from the lower and
upper tails, respectively of $\mathsf{Chisq}(n).$ That is, $L$ is quantile
$\alpha/2 =.025$ and $U$ is quantile $1-\alpha/2 =.975.$

Thus $P\left(L \le \frac{nV}{\sigma^2} \le U \right) = .95.$ After some
manipulation of inequalities we obtain 
$P\left(\frac{nV}{U} \le \sigma^2 \le \frac{nV}{L}\right) = .95),$ so that
a 95% CI for $\sigma^2$ is of the form $\left(\frac{nV}{U},\; \frac{nV}{L}\right).$

This is sometimes called a 'probability-symmetrical' CI; while $V$ is
contained in the CI, it is not at the *center* of the CI. (So the CI
is *not* symmetrical about $V$.)

As an example, suppose $n = 20$ so that $L = 3.247$ and $U = 20.483$ from R
statistical software as below or from printed tables of the chi-squared distribution. Then if $V = 20.5,$ the 95% CI is $(10.01,\, 63.14).$

```
qchisq(c(.025,.975), 10)
##  3.246973 20.483177
10*20.5/qchisq(c(.975,.025),10)
## 10.00821 63.13573
```

For simplicity, this is the CI most commonly used in practice. However,
two variations are possible:

(a) One variation is to use software to search for values
$L_c$ and $U_c$ so that $V$ turns out to be at the center of the CI.
People accustomed to symmetrical CIs for $\mu$ of the form
$\bar X \pm M,$ where the margin of error $M$ comes from a (symmetrical)
normal or t distribution, may prefer to see CIs where the point
estimate is at the center of the interval estimate. But in practice,
many types of CIs are not symmetrical in this way, and there seems to
be no practical advantage to symmetrical CIs--particularly when it is
extra work to find them.

(b) Perhaps a more useful variation is to search for $L_m$ and $U_m$ so that
the length $\left(\frac{nV}{L_m} - \frac{nV}{U_m}\right)$ of the CI is as small as possible, while maintaining $P\left(\frac{nV}{U_m} \le \sigma^2 \le \frac{nV}{L_m}\right) = .95,$ Roughly speaking larger sample sizes $n$ result in shorter CIs, and
so there is some focus on the length of CIs. There may be practical reasons
for taking the extra trouble to find the shortest CI for the population
variance.

*Note:* Response to comment. Here is a figure showing the PDF of $\mathsf{Chisq}(10).$ Quantiles .025 (3,247) and .975 (20.483) are shown as vertical red lines. Areas in each tail beyond the quantile are 2.5%, leaving 95% area between the red lines.

[image]

Comment: When we say, in your example, $x_{20,.025}$ isn't that equivalent to saying $P[Y>x_{20,.025}]=.025$ ?
If that is true, then if the cut is symmetrical shouldn't it also be $P[Y<x_{20,.975}]=.975$  ? I just don't understand why the index of $x_{1}$ is $1-α/2$ and not $α/2$ .

Comment: I'm just trying to understand, shouldn't the U quantile be also $α=.025$?

Comment: Because quantile .025 has 2.5% of the area below. And quantile .975 has 97,5% of the probability below, hence 2.5% above. // Some tables put header .025 when cutting 2.5% of the probability from the upper tail, perhaps calling it the .025 'percentage point'. But with that definition of 'percentage point' it isn't the same thing as 'percentile'. Always make a sketch.

Comment: The interval is 95% correct? Then if the L is quantile .025 , isn't there just 2.5% of the probability left left, meaning that the U quantile is also .025? I'm obviously missing something so sorry if I sound silly. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: No, according to the formal definition of quantile, $U$ is is quantile .975. (Quantile and upper tail probability are not the same.) // Do you have printed chi-squared tables? If so, look on row for df = 10 and see if you can find values 3.247 and 20.483 in the body of the table. Then look at the header? Does it have quantiles or 'percentage points'?

Comment: Percentage points. 3.247 is under .025 and and 20.48 under .975. Ok i think i got it! We make the cuts at .025 and .0975. So in the index of $x_{.025}$ it means that we make the cut at .025 and below that it remains 2.5% and at $x_{.975}$ it means that above the respective point it's the last 2.5%. I'm not sure yet but I think i almost got it. Thank you also for the graph above, just saw it and it helped!